Where can I find Sales Engagement Cadences Email Threads?
I can't seem to access the email threads created by Sales Engagement Cadences. They show up under my Leads Activity Timeline but queries don't return it.

I have tried the following queries:

SELECT ActivityId, BccAddress, CcAddress,FromAddress, RelatedToId,
Status, ThreadIdentifier FROM EmailMessage WHERE RelatedToId = 'leadId'


SELECT (SELECT ActivityDate,ActivitySubtype FROM ActivityHistories) FROM Lead where Id = 'leadId'

None of these return the emails sent using salesforce cadences. Is there any way to access these?
